# ImageButton stretch src to fill

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

This question comes up quite often, however in all examples i have found, the image src is defined in the XML. e.g `android:src="..."`

My code doesn't specificy the src untill the activity, using `ImageButton.setImageResource()` as it is a single button, performing play/stop

How do i fill the ImageButton with the src, when src is defined later?

I tryed `ImageButton.setScaleType="fitXY"`, however sdk doesn't like it using string...

[image]

UPDATE: After trying to use the suggested below, the problem still occurs. here is more explanation to help

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imgStart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    />
```

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

private ImageButton player;

protected void onCreate(){
player = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgStart);

...

if(isPlaying){
player.setImageResource(bitmap image);
}
else{
player.setImageResource(different bitmap image);
}
...
}
```

Comment: why are you not using ImageView instead of ImageButton ?

Comment: i see no reason to use ImageView instead?

Comment: I suggest you to use ImageView for showing Image becz ImageButton can't fill given all area for image,it left some area,if you not believe then try to show image using both way.

Comment: my apologies, it would seem that using image view instead gets rid of the visable background issue :) thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Use  ScaleType.CENTER_CROP instead

player .setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

It seems CENTER_CROP works as fit_xy.
but, it's not sure why it does..

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code to set `ScaleType` programatically

```
ImageButton object".setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY)
```

**"ImageButton object" should be object of class ImageButton
 (that you defined probably in xml).**

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way

```
ImageButton object.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY)
```

Use ScaleType.FIT_XY instead of fitXY in your code

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageButton.setScaleType="fitXY"
```

yes this will not work, because you have to use it properly using below code also should setAdjustViewBounds to true.like this:

```
player.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
player.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

This will definitely work!